# trigger a marker click

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-geocoder

I am using a Fusion Table and the Google Map API and would like to know if I can automatically trigger an event when a marker is placed.

Currently I can click on the map and I get a customized infowindow, but I want to do the same thing but after geocoding and placing a marker... I would like this to happen automatically.

Here is my code so far:

```
var FusionTableID = '<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'fusion_id' )?>';

var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var marker = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var local = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'lat-long' )?>);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: local,
    zoom: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'zoom' )?>
  });
  // forces a refresh to from Fusion Tables
  //var and=' geometry does not contain "'+new Date().getTime()+'"';

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    //suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
     select: "col2\x3e\x3e0",
     from: FusionTableID,
     where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      },
      map: map
    });

    layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e) {

    var point = e.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
    var latlngStr = point.split(',', 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
          });

         console.log(e.row['objectid'].value);
         var tname = e.row['name'].value; // name
         var targetDist =  e.row['description'].value; // description
        // poplulate the infowindow
         e.infoWindowHtml = "<div class=\"grid-100\"><h2>"+tname+"</h2>"+targetDist+"<hr></div>";
    });  
}


function showAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
           if (results[0].geometry.viewport) 
              map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

            // THIS DOESN'T WORK ****
            new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I have to re-build the info window inside showAddress?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)?  It isn't really possible to "trigger" a click on a FusionTablesLayer (you can, but you basically need to replicate the information in the click event, which is painful), you can query the table an create your own infowindow on the marker though.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am after and basically this is what I did on the first cut of the code, but I ran into an issue. When I queried the Fusion table to build the info window it some cases it would would return the wrong info ( not pick up on the polygon you clicked on).  Going the e.infoWindowHtml route corrected that.  Almost like it's an ordering thing with the polygons,

Comment: Maybe you should ask about that "issue".

Comment: Thanks gecodezip I will create a new thread asking the question, otherwise your recommendation is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks geocodezip

> It isn't really possible to "trigger" a click on a FusionTablesLayer (you can, but you basically need to replicate the information in the click event, which is painful), you can query the table an create your own infowindow on the marker though